# PHP: How to properly create an instance of a class within a class? (AKA use a class within a class)

Tags: php, class, oop

I am reading that the best way to use a class properties (`database class`) within another class (`html class`) is to create an instance of that class within the class (`html`). As to why, I am not sure...but anyway.

How is this done?
I have two scenarios, to see which one(s) are correct and which ones are wrong...

**Scenario A**

```
require( database.php );

class html(){
    private static $db = null;
    private static $page = null;

    public function __construct($id){
        self::bootstrap($id);
    }

    public static function bootstrap($id){
        self::$db = new database();
        self::$page = $db->page($id);
        return self::$page;
    }
}

//$page = new html('hello-world');
//print $page;
print html::bootstrap('hello-world');
```

**Scenario B**

```
//Class autoloader
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/class/' . $class . '.php';
});


//Scenario B code
class html(){
    private static $page = null;

    public static function bootstrap($id){
        self::$page = database::page($id);
        return self::$page;
    }
}

print html::bootstrap('hello-world');
```

Perhaps you have a different scenario that's appropriate, if these are the wrong approach

Comment: Read up about [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say no scenario is wrong, but scenario B is more appropriate. Since `page` was designed as static method in `database` class, that informs the intentional usage of the method.